# Python coding to sum a constant value to all elements n times

Tags: python, list, loops, integer, iteration

I have a list of integers. I need to add a `value` to all the elements in the the list.
This addition on the list must happen n times and I need a print of all the values

I have x elements in the list. So i typically created a array of x and all the elements with value n. Unable to create a loop to execute the process though in python?

Comment: Broadcast it: `K = 123 + mylist`.

Comment: @AdrianKeister: This requires `mylist` to not be a `list`, but a `numpy` `array` type.

Comment: Oh, you're right. Could also convert, then convert back. Don't know if that gains you anything, though.

Comment: `sum()` is for adding all the elements of the list togther, it's not for adding something to each element.

Comment: I tried the array function as well but unable to loop it 250 times and print all the values

Comment: @MuthyaMounika If you're adding 123 a total of 250 times, why not just add 30750 to each element of the list?

Comment: @AdrianKeister I need all the samples. for example my timestamp is at 1, the next current value occurs at 1+123, then 2+123 so on for 256 datapoints of a single packet. the next data point in the list belongs to the next packet.

Comment: Well, I'm totally confused. Could you please post a small sample of the data you have before this loop, and what you need it to look like after the loop runs? Especially include the dimensions of each array, and the sizes (i.e., the shapes of each array or list).

Comment: @AdrianKeister

My excel file is as follows:
Col A
0
25650
51200
76800
102400 and so on 392 rows

In excel for column B: B=A2+123 Similarly  C=B+123 and D=C+123
Col A.       Col B
0.              123
25650.      25773
51200.      51323
76800.      76923
102400.     102523

I will need this operation to occur 255 times.

As i have 392 rows, need to print 392*256(incl col A) data points which can be unodered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using normal forloop.

```
myList = [0, 12, 30, 32] #column A
for i in myList:
    holder = i
    temp_list=[i,]
    for x in range(10): #change range(10) to range(250)
        holder += 123
        temp_list.append(holder)
    #print(temp_list)
    print(*temp_list, sep='    ')
```

Comment: when I am already adding the 123 via dummy array, why to add 123 at new_value?
I would like to add this 123 again to the newly obtained list but still have a duplicate of that value. I would need to keep doing this addition 250 times.

Comment: My excel file is as follows: 
Col A 
0 
25650 
51200 
76800 
102400 and so on 392 rows
 In excel for column B: B=A2+123 Similarly C=B+123 and D=C+123 
Col A. Col B 
0. 123 
25650. 25773 
51200. 51323 
76800. 76923 
102400. 102523 I will need this operation to occur 255 times. As i have 392 rows, need to print 392*256(incl col A) data points which can be unodered. list A only prints Col B but not C, D etc till IW

Comment: I change my answer and add some comments. hope it solves your problem

Comment: if you need to print it without commas and brackets.
change print(temp_list) to print(*temp_list, sep='    ')

Comment: Great. If this answer solved your problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark.

Comment: Example i have the time stamp and the duration (34016) that needs to be spread over 256 datapoints by adding 123 so I dont need it as (i = ; i<n; i++) but i only want the data in line n

Comment: can you clarify your last question. and add it to the main question

Comment: I have updated the console image on the main question. The data is printed as the right triangle model of data but the only information needed is available in the 5th row which i had highlighted as i gave range(5). Also i was wondering if it is possible to print it to a list

Comment: you're print(*temp_list, sep='    ') is inside the inner loop it should be only on the main loop. please check the indention of my answer

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
myList = [YOUR LIST]
newList = [x+123 for x in myList]
print(newList)
```

Comment: Yes but that needs to be in a loop 250 times and it needs to print all the values